# While loop not breaking under logical circumstances

Tags: python, debugging, loops, while-loop

I am making a code to simulate a dice and do other stuff, but there is a while loop which isn't breaking and I don't know why.

```
import random
import math

#infinite loop
while True:
    while True:
        a = 0
        #input amount of dice
        att_die = raw_input('Attacking dice: ')
        def_die = raw_input('Defending dice: ')

        #att
        #if NaN
        if str(att_die).isdigit() == False:
            print('NaN')
        #if not NaN
        else:
            a += 1

        #def
            #if NaN
        if str(def_die).isdigit() == False:
            print('NaN')
        #if not NaN
        else:
            a +=1

        if a == 2:
            break

    if att_die >= def_die:
        no = def_die
    else:
        no = att_die

    print (no)

    x = 0
    while x <= no:
        att_loss = 0
        def_loss = 0

        roll_att = random.randint(1,6)
        roll_def = random.randint(1,6)

        if roll_att <= roll_def:
            att_loss += 1
        elif roll_att == roll_def:
            att_loss += 1
        else:
            def_loss += 1

        x += 1
        print(x)
   print('Att: -' + str(att_loss) + '\nDef: -' + str(def_loss))
```

everything works up until the last while loop, which just continuously outputs the value of x increasing.
Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, I am running 2.7.6. I don't know if that matters

Comment: Add `no` to your print statement and show the output

Answer (score 2):

`no` is a `str`, not an `int`. `x` is an `int`. In Python2, `int`s are always compare less than `str`s:

```
In [187]: 9999 < '1'
Out[187]: True
```

The solution is to convert the `str` `no` into an `int`:

```
no = int(no)
```

---

```
In [188]: 9999 < int('1')
Out[188]: False
```

---

Note that in Python3, comparing an `int` with a `str` raises a TypeError, which will save many a programmer from this pitfall.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I was that stupid. Thanks, I've been trying to figure this our for about an hour now -_-

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactored version:

```
import random
import math

DIE_SIDES = 6
WINNING_ATTACK_ODDS = 0.5 * (DIE_SIDES - 1) / DIE_SIDES

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def attack():
    """
    Does the attacker win?
    """
    return random.random() < WINNING_ATTACK_ODDS

def main():
    while True:
        att_die = get_int("Attacking dice: ")
        def_die = get_int("Defending dice: ")

        rolls = min(att_die, def_die)
        def_loss = sum(attack() for _ in range(rolls))
        att_loss = rolls - def_loss

        print("Att: -{}\nDef: -{}".format(att_loss, def_loss))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```